# Is there any way to loop through a struct with elements of different types in C?

Tags: c, struct, loops

my struct is some like this

```
typedef struct {
  type1 thing;
  type2 thing2;
  ...
  typeN thingN;
} my_struct
```

how to enumerate struct childrens in a loop such as while, or for?

Comment: what operation do you want to do to each one?

Comment: I can't see why you'd want to loop over different types. Doesn't each type require a different operation? Please explain.

Comment: curiosity, i have a function that accept a value with the order of childrens of a sctruct, example, function ("string1", "string2", 1 // this is the index of children of struct)

in function body, i know, where i will hold the strings parameters, i know that i can pass the pointer to children that i want, but, i think that were another way.
thanks for all answer

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but  you can use **[X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)** and have the preprocessor doing the iteration over all the fields of a structure:

```
//--- first describe the structure, the fields, their types and how to print them
#define X_FIELDS \
    X(int, field1, "%d") \
    X(int, field2, "%d") \
    X(char, field3, "%c") \
    X(char *, field4, "%s")

//--- define the structure, the X macro will be expanded once per field
typedef struct {
#define X(type, name, format) type name;
    X_FIELDS
#undef X
} mystruct;

void iterate(mystruct *aStruct)
{
//--- "iterate" over all the fields of the structure
#define X(type, name, format) \
         printf("mystruct.%s is "format"\n", #name, aStruct->name);
X_FIELDS
#undef X
}

//--- demonstrate
int main(int ac, char**av)
{
    mystruct a = { 0, 1, 'a', "hello"};
    iterate(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print :

```
mystruct.field1 is 0
mystruct.field2 is 1
mystruct.field3 is a
mystruct.field4 is hello
```

You can also add the name of the function to be invoked in the X_FIELDS...

Comment: X-Macro was a revelation for me. It feels kinda dirty, but kinda right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no safe way to enumerate a struct's members, unless the exact contents of the struct is known, and even in that case you have to be careful of things like struct alignment/padding.

Depending on your problem, it might be safer to have an array of your struct.

Answer (score 2):

Since you plan to handle them in a loop, I assume the different types can at least be treated alike, or have similar sizes.

If this is the case, your choice will depend on the size of the elements. If they're all the same, you can retrieve a pointer to the structure, cast it to one of your types, and increment it until you 'used up' the whole structure.

PS: Indeed, not a very safe practice. This a situation handled much better with an OO approach, taking advantage of polymorphism. Otherwise, there's no guarantees about alignment as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to iterate through struct members in C language, regardless of whether the have the same size/type or different sizes/types.

Comment: Hmm, if they were all the same type though, wouldn't you be able to use a bit of `sizeof` arithmetic and loop through the values? I agree that there's no real telling a meaningful mapping of those values without knowing the declaration order before-hand, but I think you could iterate over the values as a set.

Comment: @SeanAllred See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973643/5380098

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, you can loop through struct elements using pointer arithmetic, if they are the same type:

```c
typedef struct numbers{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} numbers;

numbers nums;

nums.a = 42;
nums.b = 99;
nums.c = 23;

int count = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int);  // 3

for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    printf("%d ", *(&nums.a + i) );      // start on the first field's address
}
```