# elements of a structure

Tags: c, data-structures

Is there a way to get all the elements of a structure, so I can use them and perhaps iterate over them and print them ?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784782/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-a-struct-with-elements-of-diferent-types-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with X-macros. See [this answer where I demonstrate exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784782/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-a-struct-with-elements-of-diferent-types-in-c/1785699#1785699).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any reflexion in C: you'll have to "fake" one.

Answer (score 0):

C does not provide a standard way to do this. However, you may be able to hack something using the C preprocessor and the `offsetof` GNU C extension.