# list_entry in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

```
user/include/linux/list.h
```

this declaration:

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
((type *)((char *)(ptr) – (unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))
```

can somebody please explain what is this and how does it work, thanks in advance

P.S. please simplify your answer as much as possible, I know about threads, processes in Linux, now I'm exploring possibilities and I'm a little bit stuck with this one.

Comment: Nowadays [list_entry](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=list_entry) macro [is defined](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h) as [container_of](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=container_of) macro (which is nearly identical to old `list_entry` version that you posted) that was greatly explained by [Radek Pazdera](https://github.com/pazdera) on [his blog](http://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/). As far as I know this change was made between kernel version [2.4.37](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h?v=2.4.37) and `2.6.11`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider two structs like this:

```
struct data {
    int something;
};

struct container {
    int something_before;
    struct data data_item;
    int something_after;
};
```

Assume you have a pointer to a `struct data` value:

```
struct data *data_ptr;
```

The `list_entry()` macro helps you to convert `data_ptr` to a pointer to the `struct container` value that holds the `struct data` value, pointed to by `ptr`:

```
struct container *cont_ptr = list_entry(data_ptr, struct container, data_item);
```

The macro works by computing the offset of `data_item` inside the `struct container`, and subtracting that many bytes from the `data_ptr` pointer. This, when cast to `struct container *`, gives a valid pointer to the `struct container` that holds this particular `struct data` "inside".

The macro can also be simplified a bit by using the builtin `offsetof()` macro:

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr) – offsetof(type, member)))
```

Comment: Compiling gives error on "–" (en dash). Change en dash to "-" (minus sign).

Answer (score 10):

An explanation of this you find [here: Section How Does This Work?](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Answer (score 2):

This macro is used to find the address of a struct given one of its member.

So, for example, suppose you have the struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int i;
    int j;
} typestruct;
```

First thing you need to know is that the last part of the macro:

```
 &((typestruct *)0)->j
```

Is used to give the offset of a member. So, it is the size, in bytes, from the **zero** memory casted to the type, to the member. In this case, it is the `sizeof(int)`, because `j` is just bellow `int i`; So lets assume this expression values `4` for simplicity. You can get the same result with the macro

```
offsetof(typestruct, j);
```

Now we want to calculate the address of `temp`, where `temp` is `typestruct temp`. To do that, we simple compute the address of the pointer minus the member position. The address of the pointer is:

```
(typestruct *)((char *) &temp.j)
```

Hence, the subtraction is:

```
&temp ==  (typestruct *)((char *) &temp.j) - offsetof(typestruct, j)
```

or, like the macro says:

```
&temp ==  (typestruct *)((char *) &temp.j) - &((typestruct *)0)->j
```

You can learn much more [here](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/), and also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524552/access-struct-members-as-if-they-are-a-single-array).

*(Parenthesis are necessary, but was eliminated for clarification)*