# Understanding container_of macro in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor

When I was browsing the Linux kernel, I found a `container_of` macro which is defined as follows:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member));})
```

I understand what does container_of do, but what I do not understand is the last sentence, which is

```
(type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member));})
```

If we use the macro as follows:

```
container_of(dev, struct wifi_device, dev);
```

The corresponding part of the last sentence would be:

```
(struct wifi_device *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(struct wifi_device, dev);
```

which looks like doing nothing.
Could anybody please fill the void here?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45923596/3625404) has **a real and intuitive example** using red-black tree `rb_node`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Your usage example `container_of(dev, struct wifi_device, dev);` might be a bit misleading as you are mixing two namespaces there.

While the first `dev` in your example refers to the name of pointer the second `dev` refers to the name of a structure member.

Most probably this mix up is provoking all that headache. In fact the `member` parameter in your quote refers to the name given to that member in the container structure.

Taking this container for example:

```
struct container {
  int some_other_data;
  int this_data;
}
```

And a pointer `int *my_ptr` to the `this_data` member you'd use the macro to get a pointer to `struct container *my_container` by using:

```
struct container *my_container;
my_container = container_of(my_ptr, struct container, this_data);
```

Taking the offset of `this_data` to the beginning of the struct into account is essential to getting the correct pointer location.

Effectively you just have to subtract the offset of the member `this_data` from your pointer `my_ptr` to get the correct location.

That's exactly what the last line of the macro does.

Comment: For those of you who need more detailed explanation: [Radek Pazdera](https://twitter.com/radekpazdera) [explained](http://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/) [container_of](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=container_of) macro (`include/linux/kernel.h`) really clearly on [his blog](http://radek.io/). [BTW](http://www.tux.org/lkml/#contributors): [list_entry](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=list_entry) macro (`include/linux/list.h`) used to be defined [very similarly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550404/list-entry-in-linux), but now is defined as `container_of`.

Comment: Also this blogpost by Greg Kroah-Hartman may be useful: http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html

Comment: In principle, that's a nice answer, except that it does not really answer considerable piece of the question? E.g., what does the last line of code achieve and how?

Comment: When I follow this example, using GCC I get `error: initialization from incompatible pointer type`.  Is this due to the `const` in the macro definition as per this thread?https://stackoverflow.com/a/39963179/1256234

Answer (score 27):

The last sentence cast:

```
(type *)(...)
```

a pointer to a given `type`. The pointer is calculated as offset from a given pointer `dev`:

```
( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) )
```

When you use the `cointainer_of` macro, you want to retrieve the structure that contains the pointer of a given field. For example:

```
struct numbers {
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
} n;

int *ptr = &n.two;
struct numbers *n_ptr;
n_ptr = container_of(ptr, struct numbers, two);
```

You have a pointer that points in the middle of a structure (and you know that is a pointer to the filed `two` [*the field name in the structure*]), but you want to retrieve the entire structure (`numbers`). So, you calculate the offset of the filed `two` in the structure:

```
offsetof(type,member)
```

and subtract this offset from the given pointer. The result is the pointer to the start of the structure. Finally, you cast this pointer to the structure type to have a valid variable.

Answer (score 20):

conatainer_of() macro in Linux Kernel -

When it comes to managing several data structures in code, you'll almost always need to embed one structure into another and retrieve them at any moment without being asked questions about memory offsets or boundaries. Let's say you have a struct person, as defined here:

```
 struct person { 
     int age; 
     int salary;
     char *name; 
 } p;
```

By only having a pointer on age or salary, you can retrieve the whole structure wrapping (containing) that pointer. As the name says, the container_of macro is used to find the container of the given field of a structure. The macro is defined in include/linux/kernel.h and looks like the following:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({               \ 
   const typeof(((type *)0)->member) * __mptr = (ptr);   \ 
   (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member)); })
```

Don't be afraid of the pointers; just see them as follows:

```
container_of(pointer, container_type, container_field);
```

Here are the elements of the preceding code fragment:

- pointer: This is the pointer to the field in the structure
- container_type: This is the type of structure wrapping (containing) the pointer
- container_field: This is the name of the field to which
  pointer points inside the structure

Let's consider the following container:

```
struct person { 
    int age; 
    int salary; 
    char *name; 
};
```

Now, let's consider one of its instances, along with a pointer to the age member:

```
struct person somebody; 
[...] 
int *age_ptr = &somebody.age;
```

Along with a pointer to the name member (age_ptr),you can use the container_of macro in order to get a pointer to the whole structure (container) that wraps this member by using the following:

```
struct person *the_person; 
the_person = container_of(age_ptr, struct person, age);
```

container_of takes the offset of age at the beginning of the struct into account to get the correct pointer location. If you subtract the offset of the field age from the pointer age_ptr, you will get the correct location. This is what the macro's last line does:

```
(type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );
```

Applying this to a real example, gives the following:

```
struct family { 
    struct person *father; 
    struct person *mother; 
    int number_of_sons; 
    int family_id; 
} f; 

/*   
 * Fill and initialise f somewhere   */      [...]

 /* 
  * pointer to a field of the structure 
  * (could be any (non-pointer) member in the structure) 
  */ 
   int *fam_id_ptr = &f.family_id; 
   struct family *fam_ptr; 

   /* now let us retrieve back its family */ 
   fam_ptr = container_of(fam_id_ptr, struct family, family_id);
```

The container_of macro is mainly used in generic containers in the kernel.

That's all about container_of macro in kernel.

Comment: This is much better explanation, atleast for a kernel noob like me. So upvoting this.

Answer (score 11):

It is an utilisation of a gcc extension, the [statements expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). If you see the macro as something returning a value, then the last line would be :

```
return (struct wifi_device *)( (char *)__mptr - offset(struct wifi_device, dev);
```

See the linked page for an explanation of compound statements. Here is an example :

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int b;
    b = 5;
    b = ({int a; 
            a = b*b; 
            a;});
    printf("b %d\n", b); 
}
```

The output is

> b 25

Answer (score 5):

A little real context says clearer, below **use red-black tree as example**, which is the
way that I understand `container_of`.

as `Documentation/rbtree.txt` states, in linux kernel code, it's not rb_node contain data
entry, rather

> Data nodes in an rbtree tree are structures containing a struct
>   rb_node member.

`struct vm_area_struct` (in file `include/linux/mm_types.h:284`) is such a structure,

in the same
file, there is a macro `rb_entry` which is defined as

```
#define rb_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

**clearly, `rb_entry` is same as `container_of`.**

at `mm/mmap.c:299` inside function definition `browse_rb`, there is a usage of `rb_entry`:

```
static int browse_rb(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    /* two line code not matter */
    struct rb_node *nd, *pn = NULL; /*nd, first arg, i.e. ptr. */
    unsigned long prev = 0, pend = 0;

    for (nd = rb_first(root); nd; nd = rb_next(nd)) {
        struct vm_area_struct *vma;
        vma = rb_entry(nd, struct vm_area_struct, vm_rb);   
        /* -- usage of rb_entry (equivalent to container_of) */
        /* more code not matter here */
```

now it is clear, in `container_of(ptr, type, member)`,

- `type` is the container struct, here `struct vm_area_struct`
- `member` is name of a member of `type` instance, here `vm_rb`, which is of type `rb_node`,
- `ptr` is a pointer pointing `member` of an `type` instance, here `rb_node *nd`.

what `container_of` do is, as in this example,

- **given address of `obj.member` (here `obj.vm_rb`), return the
  address of `obj`.**
- since a struct is a block of contiguous memory, **address of `obj.vm_rb` minus
  `offset between the struct and member` will be the container's address.**

`include/linux/kernel.h:858`    --  definition of `container_of`

`include/linux/rbtree.h:51`     -- definition of `rb_entry`

`mm/mmap.c:299`                 -- usage of `rb_entry`

`include/linux/mm_types.h:284`  -- `struct vm_area_struct`

`Documentation/rbtree.txt:`     -- Documentation of red-black tree

`include/linux/rbtree.h:36`     -- definition of `struct rb_node`

**P.S.**

Above files are in current develop version, i.e, `4.13.0-rc7`.

`file:k` mean kth line in `file`.

Answer (score 4):

Very useful link for understanding container_of macro in linux kernel.
https://linux-concepts.blogspot.com/2018/01/understanding-containerof-macro-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Most Simplest Implementation of Container _of macro is below , It reduces all complex checking of type and works

```
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))
```

ptr will give address of member and just subtract offset difference and you will 
get start address.

Example usage

```
struct sample {
    int mem1;
    char mem2;
    int mem3;
};
int main(void)
{

struct sample sample1;

printf("Address of Structure sample1 (Normal Method) = %p\n", &sample1);
printf("Address of Structure sample1 (container_of Method) = %p\n", 
                        container_of(&sample1.mem3, struct sample, mem3));

return 0;
}
```