# How do I call a method in an owning object in c++?

Tags: c++

What is the syntax for calling a method in an owning object from an owned object in c++?

**Parent class:**

```
class Parent
{
private:
    Child child;

public:
    Parent()
    {
        addChild(child);
    }

    void MethodToBeCalled(int someArgument)
    {

    }
};
```

**Child class:**

```
class Child
{
private:
    void myVoid()
    {
        //Call parent method somehow
    }

public:
    Child()
    {

    }
};
```

I tried to make my question as simple and generic as possible (to be of benefit to as many as possible). Let me know if I can make it even clearer.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to know a reference to `Parent` in the `Child` class to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, thank you! but I don't get what that syntax would look like in my example?

Comment: There's no "parent-child" relationship between your objects in the code sample you presented. This makes the question title highly misleading. There's an "aggregate-member" ("container-containee") relationship. But this relationship does not in general imply any access from the containee to the container. There are specific hacks for this (like the well-known `container_of` macro), but they have restricted applicability.

Comment: @AnT oops! thank you! Can you please suggest a better title?

Comment: @AnT is it possible to achieve this by sending a reference to the container when creating the containee (as an argument in the containees constructor)?

Comment: It's misleading to call this a "parent object". It's an "owning object" really.

Comment: BTW, what's `childComponent` type and how is it related to `Child` type?

Comment: @AnT oops again! Thank you for pointing out, edited.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet sorry! what would be a better title? thanks

Comment: Didn't I just suggest one?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet true! Edited, thanks!

Comment: Better. Now, remove the inheritance (i.e. remove Component) as that's a complete red herring and a bit confusing. Similarly, rename your classes.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet thank you! removed the inheritance, whats a better term for Child?

Comment: You could call them `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a example. I had to modify your code a bit to get it compile:

```
class Component {};

class Parent;

class Child   : public Component
{
private:
    inline void myVoid();
    Parent &parent_ref;

public:
    Child(Parent &pr) : parent_ref{pr} {}
};

class Parent   : public Component {
private:
    Child child;

public:
    Parent() : child{*this}
    {
        // addChildComponent(child);
    }

    void MethodToBeCalled(int someArgument)
    {

    }
};

inline void Child::myVoid()
{
    parent_ref.MethodToBeCalled(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your `Child` object is a member subobject of `Parent` class (as in your example), you can use the `container_of` trick (see [Understanding container_of macro in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-linux-kernel))

```
class Child
{
private:
    void myVoid();
};

class Parent
{
public:
    Child child;

    void MethodToBeCalled(int someArgument)
    {
    }
};

void Child::myVoid()
{
    container_of(this, Parent, child)->MethodToBeCalled(42);
}
```

Obviously, tricks like this immediately restrict the usability of your `Child` class to always being a member of `Parent` class (at least when you intend to call `myVoid()` method on it).

A much better idea would be to just pass a reference to parent object to child object.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can't, because `Child` and `Parent` have nothing in common except that they both inherit `Component`. `Child` has to have a `Parent` object in order to call `MethodToBeCalled()`.

Comment: I've heard that it should be possible by sending a reference to the parent in the childs constructor. But I don't understand what that syntax would look like?

Comment: Create a `Parent` object in your class, then you can add an argument to the construtor `Child(Parent& parent)`. Then you can set the parent object from your class to that parent (`this->parent = parent;` for example). After you can call `MethodToBeCalled()` like this `parent.MethodToBeCalled(0);`

Comment: Thank you! This comment is the closest to what ended up working for me.