# Replacing the container_of macro used in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux

On trying to understand the functionality of **container_of()** from the source code linux kernel [Definition of container_of](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L835), I found out that the below line in the definition of the macro looks like doing nothing.

> const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \

So, I wrote a simple C program without the said line and tried to the compare the obtained results.
Basically, I am trying to **Understand how is the new implementation *my_contianer_of()* different from *container_of() ?*** when both the implementation give same results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

#define my_container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
        (char *)ptr - offsetof(type, member);})

struct container {
    int *i;
    char c;
    float f;
};

void foo(char *cptr)
{
    printf("foo  : %p\n", my_container_of(cptr, struct container, c));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct container tc;

    printf("&tc  : %p\n", &tc);
    printf("cof  : %p\n", container_of(&tc.c, struct container, c));
    printf("mycof: %p\n", my_container_of(&tc.c, struct container, c));

    foo(&tc.c);

    return 0;
}
```

The below is the sample output for the above c program.

```
&tc  : 0x7ffca543e0c0
cof  : 0x7ffca543e0c0
mycof: 0x7ffca543e0c0
foo  : 0x7ffca543e0c0
```

Please don't mark this question as the duplicate of any other question or this [Understanding container_of macro in the linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel/45923596#45923596) as those questions did not provide the required answer for my query.

Comment: There could be edge cases that the simplified version does not handle. Or it's just a matter of eliminating compiler implicit typecasting warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation isn't type safe. It doesn't make sure that the pointer you pass is to the same type as the member, which could lead to bugs. So, for instance:

```
my_container_of(&tc.f, struct container, c)
```

Will compile just fine. The kernel version will at least issue a warning about incompatible pointer types. Or flat out cause compilation to halt, depending on your GCC flags.

Naturally, the kernel version doesn't prevent  *all* bugs (if `f` and `c` were of the same type, for instance). But this is one it can catch, and should.