# How can I get the process descriptor from a PID in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pid

I am trying to figure out how to get the process descriptor from a PID.

From  http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/153873-getting-task_struct-process-using-its-pid.html,  for Linux kernel 2.4

```c
static inline struct task_struct *find_task_by_pid(int pid)
{
    struct task_struct *p, **htable = &pidhash[pid_hashfn(pid)];

    for(p = *htable; p && p->pid != pid; p = p->pidhash_next)
        ;

    return p;
}
```

The link seems to say that `pidhash[pid_hashfn(pid)]` is a pointer to a `task_struct` object whose PID is value `pid`.

But that doesn't seem to be true from the book Understanding The Linux Kernel, which talks about Linux kernel 2.6.11. I am not sure if the relevant code is the same in 2.6.11 and in 2.4. From the book, I learned that `pidhash[pid_hashfn(pid)]` has type `hlist_head`, which is a pointer to an `hlist_node` object. The `hlist_node` object is `pids[0].pid_chain` of a `task_struct` object. Then  how can I obtain the `task_struct` object from `pidhash[pid_hashfn(pid)]`?

Note that

- I am asking this just for the purposes of reading Understanding the Linus Kernel (Linux kernel 2.6.11), so I am not asking about the recent Linux kernel versions, although it doesn't hurt that you can also mention how it is done in the recent Linux kernel versions.
- I guess the difficulty I have here is related to my previous question [Whose address shall the node of a linked list store: other node, or data structure having a node as a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359598/whose-address-shall-the-node-of-a-linked-list-store-other-node-or-data-structu)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In kernel 2.6.11 `task_struct` contains array [`pids[PIDTYPE_MAX]`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/include/linux/sched.h#L589) so that given task placed in several hash-tables simultaniously.

[`pidhash`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/kernel/pid.c#L31) contains pointers to [`PIDTYPE_MAX`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/include/linux/pid.h#L4) hash-tables. `pidhash[i]` is a pointer to beginning of *i*-th hash-table. Thus, `pidhash[type][pid_hashfn(nr)]` is a pointer to linked list.

It is better to find `struct pid *` to entry in task's  [`pids[type]`] element with given pid type `type` and pid `nr` using kernel function [`find_pid(type, nr)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/kernel/pid.c#L134).

Then you can convert (non-`NULL`) pointer to `struct pid` into pointer to `struct task_struct` using `container-of`-based macro [`pid_task`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/include/linux/pid.h#L22).