# Where is run_node defined in the sched_fair.c of Linux 2.6.33?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, include

I am reading [Robert Love's Book Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003V4ATI0).

It uses the 2.6.33 kernel for demonstration.

I have been going through certain parts of the source and can't find out where is the initial definition of many things. A lot of things are just used, like "magic" without me finding the definition.

One example:

```
static struct sched_entity *__pick_next_entity(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq)
{
    struct rb_node *left = cfs_rq->rb_leftmost;

    if (!left)
        return NULL;

    return rb_entry(left, struct sched_entity, run_node);
}

static struct sched_entity *__pick_last_entity(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq)
{
    struct rb_node *last = rb_last(&cfs_rq->tasks_timeline);

    if (!last)
        return NULL;

    return rb_entry(last, struct sched_entity, run_node);
}
```

This is in `kernel/sched_fair.c` lines `384` and `394` in 2.6.33 kernel.

Where is the `run_node` coming from?

I have grep ed the entire source base over [here](https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=run_node&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true), and I have not found any definition of `run_node` that would allow it to be used like this.

There is a [declaration](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/219d54332a09e8d8741c1e1982f5eae56099de85/include/linux/sched.h#L448) in the `sched_entity` structure, but nothing outside of it that would allow it to be used like this.

I cannot understand how things are organized, its really confusing.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run_node` you see is not a variable, it's the `.run_node` field of the [`sched_entity`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1152) structure.

[`rb_entry()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/rbtree.h#L133) is a macro which is basically an alias for [`container_of()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L698):

```
#define rb_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

The `container_of()` macro is used to get a pointer to a struct given a pointer to a known field (`ptr`), the structure type (`type`) and the field name (`member`). In your case `left` is a pointer to the `run_node` field of some `struct sched_entity`, so `container_of()` is basically used to get a pointer to the appropriate `sched_entity`.

See also: [Understanding container_of macro in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel).