# A structure contains a doubly linked list member. Why does the order of this member in the structure affect some of my operation results?

Tags: c, linux, memory-alignment

I transplanted a doubly linked list from the linux kernel, but I found some problems when testing the inserted elements of the linked list,the test code is as follows.when i run the test case,i find the result is so weird[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esKXh.png).However I put the **stu_list** member at the beginning of struct student,the result is normal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Z5d.png).Please tell me why there is such a result and the principle,thanks!

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
struct student {
    int id;
    int grades;
    struct list_head stu_list;
};

int main(void) {
    struct student stu1, stu2;
    struct student *p;
    struct list_head *pos;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&stu1.stu_list);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&stu2.stu_list);

    for (volatile int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        p = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        p->id = i;
        p->grades = 90 + i;
        list_add_tail(&p->stu_list, &stu1.stu_list);
    }
    printf("list add result:\n");
    list_for_each(pos, &stu1.stu_list) {
        printf("ID = %d,grades = %d\n", ((struct student *) pos)->id, ((struct student *) pos)->grades);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't try to show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Also please take some time to lead read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Off topic but... the use of the `volatile` keyword is completely redundant here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `(struct student *) pos)`.

The C standard allows to convert a pointer to a struct to a pointer of its first member.  Therefore the code works only if the `stu_list` is the first member of the parent struct.

Otherwise, you should use `container_of`-like macro to transform a pointer to `struct list_head` to the embedding structure which is `struct student`.

Please read [container_of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel) post or [other post](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) for more information.

To fix the issue add the following macro:

```
#define list_entry(ptr,type,member) \ 
         ((type*)(((char*)ptr) - offsetof(type,member)))
```

Now the body of printing loop should be:

```
list_for_each(pos, &stu1.stu_list) {
        struct student *s = list_entry(pos, struct student, stu_list);
        printf("ID = %d,grades = %d\n", s->id, s->grades);
}
```