UB with reinterpret_cast
Am i allowed to do this safely, assuming func is only ever called with &container_instance.bar?

struct foo_t { int val; };
struct bar_t { int val; };

struct container
{
    foo_t foo;
    bar_t bar;
};

void func(bar_t* b)
{
    std::uintptr_t addr_of_b = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(b);
    // get address of foo
    addr_of_b -= offsetof(container, bar);
    foo_t* f = reinterpret_cast<foo_t*>(addr_of_b);

    // access f
    f->val = 42;
}

From cppreference (reinterpret_cast) i found these two quotes, which seem to be somewhat applicable in this scenario. However, item 3) does not talk about the case when i modify the integral value and item 6) seems to be concerned with accessing foo_t*  directly from the address of bar_t*. Is the above mentioned scenario defined somewhere?


A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to have its original value, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be dereferenced safely (the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations)




An glvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to another type T2. The result is that of *reinterpret_cast<T2*>(p), where p is a pointer of type “pointer to T1” to the object or function designated by expression. No temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion functions are called. The resulting reference can only be accessed safely if it is type-accessible.



This is not guaranteed to work across architectures. Pointer arithmetic should be done with pointers, not integers. Use char* instead of uintptr_t. Still probably technically UB though, but it at least has a chance to work with segmented pointers.

So basically i would have to verify by checking the assembly produced by the compiler on a given architecture?

I second the advice of getting rid of uintptr_t. char * should work well enough in practice.

Checking assembly in general isn't enough, since this can in theory break some compiler optimizations in some specific cases. (Though it should work in practice.) Don't overthink it. The linux kernel famously has a macro that does the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15832301/2752075

@HolyBlackCat Thanks for mentioning the container_of macro, i will be having a look at that!

in windows this kind of code frquently used. look for CONTAINING_RECORD macro. with it your code will be look like, void func(bar_t* b){ CONTAINING_RECORD(b, container, bar)->foo.val = 42; }

I think it is pedantically UB, but would work in practice with all 3 big compilers.

If you want the address of b add a getter function to the struct that will return the address of b. I am fairly certain compilers will optimize that by inlining it.

You might be able to do it safely (as a compiler implementation defined behavior), if your platform has flat addressing.  Do you care about portability?  Does your code need to work on non-flat architectures?
