# Need clarification on the content given in the Linux Kernel by Robert Love

Tags: process, linux-kernel

I am new in LKD and I was reading book by Robert Love. I stuck in understand one concept as follow.

Similarly, it is possible to iterate over a process’s children with

```
struct task_struct *task;
struct list_head *list;
list_for_each(list, &current->children) {
    task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
    /* task now points to one of current’s children */
}
```

Also I would be great if somebody explain the list_entry arguments work?

I am having difficult in understanding above code snippet specially `list_for_each` works.

Comment: Have you tried [looking it up](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.1/include/linux/list.h#L375)?

Comment: @larsmans yes and also I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550404/list-entry-in-linux but still I didn't get it .

Answer (score 1):

`list_for_each` is a macro [defined as](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.1/include/linux/list.h#L375)

```
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
        for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

Since macros in C are expanded by textual substitution, the piece of code you cite becomes

```
for (list = (&current->children)->next; list != (&current->children); list = list->next) {
    task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
    /* task now points to one of current’s children */
}
```

This code walks a circular linked list starting at the node `(&current->children)->next`, until it comes back to `(&current->children)->next`.