# Why previous kernel cast a pointer to unsigned long in C

Tags: c, kernel

The simiar code also appeared here: [list_entry in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550404/list-entry-in-linux)

But my question is that why cast it to `unsigned long`? Because according to C99 6.3.2.3, the behavior is undefined or implementation defined to cast a pointer to interger

> 6.3.2.3:
>   6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

So why previous kernel cast a pointer to unsigned long ? Is it a bug?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foobar{
    unsigned int foo;
}tmp;
printf("\taddress and offset of tmp->foo= %p\n",
       (struct foobar *)(((char *)&tmp.foo)
               - ((unsigned long)&((struct foobar *)0)->foo)));
```

I use gcc and a x86_64 machine , and I know the code from this [tutorial](https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Comment: Are you sure that compiles? I can't parse the final `0`. In fact, that makes little sense. It uses both an instance (`tmp`) but also the `NULL`-trick. Why?!11

Comment: Yeah.. why?....

Comment: This is really bad... Seems like you need `container_of` macro.

Comment: The final `0` is a syntax error, the rest is a very aweful way to calculate the address of `tmp`.

Comment: `&((struct foobar *)0)->foo` is this an attempt to create a null pointer of type `(struct foobar *)` and then dereference it?

Comment: Please also note that the format specifier `%p` requires a `void*`.

Comment: Here is a great explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic

Comment: @giusti it's a pointer to adress 0

Comment: Well, now I know one place to *never* trust a degree from.  Casting a pointer to `unsigned long`??!?!?!  Ouch.  Looks like an example of "Those that can, do.  Those that can't, teach".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Note the subdomain name :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh Lord.  :-/

Comment: Shouldn't this throw a segmentation fault? Because he is dereferencing a NULL pointer?

Comment: @KamiKaze Not dereferencing, just taking an address.

Comment: @Kami Kaze it's not a null pointer it's a pointer to adress 0...

Comment: @MartinChekurov What's the difference?

Comment: It's not an example of great code, but as long as it's only to teach how structures are laid out in memory for illustrative purposes, it's okay. Portable code shoud use `offsetof` instead. Some compiler standard libraries actually use this trick to implement `offsetof` although they'd probably use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long`.

Comment: size_t is unsigned integer type, which is 32 bit, and not okay for 64 bit pointer, although in this case, there will be no structure offset which is bigger than 2^32

Comment: @RyanChen `unsigned long` can be 32-bit integer type too.

Comment: The only unsigned integer type which is guaranteed to hold pointer is `uintptr_t`

Comment: @WeatherVane is there any machine which the `pointer` is 64 bit and `long` is 32 bit?

Comment: That's not the point. An `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits, and the compiler writer can choose to do that.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, I will use `uintptr_t` from now, thank you

Comment: @RyanChen why not? [The majority of personal computers nowadays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) have [64-bit pointer and 32-bit long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384502/995714) although most 64-bit OSes have 64-bit `long`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list\_entry in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550404/list-entry-in-linux)

Comment: @anatolyg No, my question is different. I emphasize on the cast. Already edit it to make it more clear

Comment: @giusti the difference is it's pointing to a valid address - 0(you can dereference and all that), but a null pointer is not valid (you cant dereference etc)

Comment: `unsigned long` will be sufficient unless `struct foobar` is larger than 4GB, and in that case we'd have serious problems with it anyway...  (note that we're in kernel code here, which gets to make a lot of other assumptions about pointers, and doesn't need to be strictly conforming).

Answer (score 0):

This code implements `container_of` macro in the Linux kernel.

The only compiler which *officially* suitable for Linux kernel is `gcc`, and it has `unsigned long` type of the same size as a pointer on all supported platforms. (E.g, for 64-bit platforms `gcc` follows [LP64](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html) types model, which has 64-bit `long`).

So, conversion from the pointer to `unsigned long` and back is valid on all those platforms.

---

Modern `container_of` [implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L929) in the Linux kernel doesn't use `unsigned long` for pointers arithmetic, but operates directly with `void*` - this is another [C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) of gcc.

Comment: Why use void* instead of char*?

Comment: `Why use void* instead of char*?` - This question is better addressed to Linux kernel developers themselves. I may guess that conversion to `void*` is preferred because it doesn't require explicit cast.

Comment: Actually, given that the specific address we're casting points into a struct at address 0, the size of `unsigned long` isn't an issue unless `sizeof (struct foobar)` is larger than `ULONG_MAX` (which is at least 4GB).