# Printing the structure using a single line in C?

Tags: c, structure

Is there any possible way in C (by using any function or any such kind) so that we can print the contents in a structure of different datatypes using a  single line?
Say for eg:

```
typedef struct ABC{
   int a;
   char b;
   long c;
}ABC1;
```

To print this we need to write:
`printf("%d %s %ld",ABC1.a,ABC1.b,ABC1.c)`

Any other method so that i can print like
`printf("????",????ABC1)`??

Comment: `printf()` does not have some magical format specifier that can correctly recognise an arbitrary user-defined struct type, and cannot work out the type of an argument unless you correctly specify it in the format string.  You can create a function which knows how to print a `struct ABC` with the desired format, but it will not know how to print some other struct type.

Comment: The format string should be `"%d %c %ld"` to match the actual arguments. Answer to the actual question is no, C has no "introspection" capability to figure out at runtime what a `struct` is made up of. To get and idea of the difficulties, see [Is there a way to print struct members in a loop without naming each member in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27497861).

Comment: @dxiv Why would it have to figure it out in run-time? Simply do it in compile-time, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glibc allows you to establish your own format specifiers for `printf` and family to let you print UDTs, which would not otherwise be possible, through some extensions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <printf.h> /* For PA_POINTER */

struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    double b;
};

struct print_info;
int handler(FILE *stream, const struct print_info *i, 
        const void* const *args)
{
    const struct MyStruct *ptr = *( (const struct MyStruct**) (*args) );
    int rc = fprintf(stream, "a: %d, b: %f\n", ptr->a, ptr->b);

    return rc;
}

int print_arginfo (const struct printf_info *info, size_t n,
                      int *argtypes)
{
  if (n > 0)
    argtypes[0] = PA_POINTER;
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct MyStruct s = {55, -3.14};
    /* We're gonna use the M specifier */
    int spec = 'M';
    int rc = register_printf_function(spec, handler, print_arginfo);

    if (rc != 0)
        return 1;

    printf("%M", &s);

};
```

You may find the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html#Customizing-Printf).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code probably wouldn't compile. You have defined ABC1 to be a typedef of the ABC struct. ABC1 is not a variable, so you cannot view the contents of ABC1.a.

Assuming you created a variable of type ABC1, you cannot "dump" the contents of the structure in a "logical" format using printf. The printf function receives a memory address and displays its contents based on the string given. The printf function cannot know the format of the structure if it only has a pointer to the memory (i.e. a bunch of bytes with no way of knowing what "type" of bytes).

Answer (score 2):

No. Best solution would be to write a method like:

1. `void printABC(struct ABC*)` or
2. `char* abcToString(struct ABC*)` (and then print via `%s`).

Option 2 is probably better and can be used eg to write to file and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No, [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) only has support for format specifiers for pre-defined data types, not for user defined data type (`struct`). Moreover, `printf()` also has no way to automatically *learn* the types of member variables of your `struct`.

You need to roll your own function to achieve the task you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @john3136 said .

but here is an example for 1 .

```
void printABC(ABC1 *ABC) /* can also use 'struct ABC*' */
{
   printf("%d %c %ld",ABC->a,ABC->b,ABC->c);
   /* Equivalent to the below */
   /* printf("%d %s %ld",(*ABC).a,(*ABC).b,(*ABC).c); */
}
```

So now everytime you want to print the whole thing you just  type something like

```
    ABC1 xyz;

    /* fill xyz here*/

    printABC(&xyz);
```

and It should type everything inside of `ABC1` in one line.

Comment: Please be careful: you pass **`ABC`** as a pointer, and then use `ABC` **`1`** as an object. You should fix before downvotes fall...

Comment: `void printABC(struct *ABC)` This won't even compile. If you meant `void printABC(struct ABC *abc)` maybe, then `ABC.a` would need to be `abc->d` and so on.

Comment: P.S. With all due respect to @l3x who just edited the answer for the better, but the printf format is still wrong (should be `%c` not `%s`) and the subsequent `printABC(&ABC1);` won't compile since `ABC1` is a typedef. Honestly, I don't understand whomever upvoted this answer *after* my previous comment *after* @SergeBallesta's initial comment.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, I missed a couple. Should be fine now.

Comment: @l3x Looks good to me now. Though it's basically *your* answer at this point, if you compare the *before* and *after*. That was a commendable rescue op ;-)

Comment: indeed its a whole new answer ! thanks guys . sincere apologies I haven't slept for 2 days but felt like answering some questions .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a somewhat modern C compiler, you can use a type-generic macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   int a;
   char b;
   long c;
} ABC;

// printf conversion specifiers:
#define CS(x)   \
  _Generic((x), \
    int:  "%d", \
    char: "%c", \
    long: "%ld")


int main (void)
{
  ABC abc = {1, 'a', 2};

  printf(CS(abc.a), abc.a); printf(" ");
  printf(CS(abc.b), abc.b); printf(" ");
  printf(CS(abc.c), abc.c); printf(" ");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to define macros for the format string and corresponding argument:

```
#define ABCformat "%d,%c:%ld"
#define ABCarg(x) (x).a, (x).b, (x).c
```

and use it like this:

```
   ABC1 abc = {1, 'c', 42};
   printf("abc=" ABCformat "\n", ABCarg(abc));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro to describe the structure, and then the macro could be used to help create the structure definition, and the pretty printer.

So, your code could look like:

```
PSTRUCT(ABC, (int, a), (char, b), (long, c));

int main () {
    ABC abc = {1, 'a', 2};
    printf("%s\n", tostring_ABC(&abc));
}
```

With the advantage that if you define another structure the same way, you will get a new print function available to you.

```
PSTRUCT(XYZ, (int, x), (double, y), (const char *, z));
```

The `PSTRUCT` macro expands into a structure definition and a function that walks the structure and emits values into a string.

```
#define PSTRUCT(N, ...) \
        typedef struct { XX(PSTRUCT_ARG, __VA_ARGS__) } N; \
        const char *tostring_##N (const N *x) { \
            static _Thread_local char buf[512]; \
            int len = 0; \
            XX(PSTRUCT_ARG_PRINT, __VA_ARGS__) \
            return buf; \
        }
```

There are helper macros to properly expand the individual fields into the structure definition and to print the field value.

```
#define PSTRUCT_ARG(X) PSTRUCT_ARG2 X
#define PSTRUCT_ARG2(X, Y) X Y;
#define PSTRUCT_ARG_PRINT(X) PSTRUCT_ARG_PRINT2 X
#define PSTRUCT_ARG_PRINT2(X, Y) \
        len += snprintf(buf+len, sizeof(buf)-len, CS(x->Y), #Y, x->Y);
```

The `CS` macro is as defined in [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392113/315052). And the iterating `XX` macro is defined as:

```
#define XX(X, ...) \
        XX_X(__VA_ARGS__, XX_5, XX_4, XX_3, XX_2, XX_1) \
        (X, __VA_ARGS__)
#define XX_X(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,X,...) X
#define XX_1(X, _)      X(_)
#define XX_2(X, _, ...) X(_) XX_1(X, __VA_ARGS__)
#define XX_3(X, _, ...) X(_) XX_2(X, __VA_ARGS__)
#define XX_4(X, _, ...) X(_) XX_3(X, __VA_ARGS__)
#define XX_5(X, _, ...) X(_) XX_4(X, __VA_ARGS__)
```

How it works is briefly described in [a different answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319010/315052).

> <sub>For simplicity, the empty structure case is ignored.</sub>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNhb9owEIa/51ecQKxOa@gI8IWMSox1VaUtQsC2oHWKgmPAUuagxGjdEL@dnU0ggdLywSTv@Xl9uTuz@oKxXTXicyE5@D7xKTQaDRueLMh/vh/4JAi@94P@6GEcBFQrHbO2zdoyq2PWZpnUZiXQtopztGWTIoQ02qCfT825fnlT0zjYeR7k1MExwTxdHSyIV85sXSKct4j2JaL1FtG5RLRfEEdkMCbPh5oFD1zyVDCCEs01IVVX/1eglvVqUeWgs2WYdo86O@pxIheFHhdAlKxnMe/mgfmJEVwf9KyCud3ewg8O/HnFmQK15OXUYZWkSiQSVAIzDnMRxzzSxB@hlrAKRZohEiqIeMZSgVu0QabSNVPrVAM8jjKqCTKZDu8pfH68//Ip8Ppf74tCDseT0bfBhHgvplH9XXHclDvCRs9svltneFpm2ILnlmCWyEzlX6wStBByEVSrHpB9xINrbMamROhfpkIlGASTZcrDKIgTFsZ7k9l6/rPTdH65ZwQ2DWIuoQfvz0On6QbD0aM3OUv6FEg51k3qo8pW2/NSaZr4dvnVKV2msqyHcYpzCVP3Unyf05nXXnzFMQ/mvkWSugQ3PcjkCgut5gS/4QY1Cpn4xxPzbteNoG9B/W6KU1@dUjCP7q4qJIvXEYcPmYpE0ljeWdZhMPofBxQIulIIkSK6HRRm@lHfAArMtl3L0o34HQoJBNtq8kIQwhnD1myaFK7CKwrO1jWhPMtKLXuSeD2OA4IIeYeMdtzudv8B)