# Implementing PRI macros 'portably'

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, freestanding

The C99 specified inttypes.h header includes macros for providing format specifiers for the fixed-width integer types provided by stdint.h (beginning with PRI).  While stdint.h is on the 'freestanding' list of headers and thus is always provided by the implementation, inttypes.h is not.

This means that when compiling for an unhosted environment (say bare-metal), you must provide inttypes.h yourself if you want to provide a standards-compliant printf that can handle fixed-width types.

However, I cannot figure out how to correctly determine at compile-time what each macro should be without manually inspecting the implementation's stdint.h, a task that would need to be repeated not just for each target platform, but for every supported compiler.

I tried an implementation via C11's _Generic but [discovered one of the limitations of that feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392467/can-multiple-generic-be-used-to-create-a-string-literal).

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: **C18 - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment** Any library facilities available to a freestanding program, other than the minimal set required by Clause 4, are implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. In essence, `inttypes.h` *exists* to give you portability, you can't "guess" it. It has to be given by the compiler. On top of that, theoretically, there just might not exist a `printf` format specifier to print the types from `stdint`.

> a standard way to do this?

Yes - contact your compiler provider and make a feature request. While waiting for it, read your compiler documentation and/or source or contact upstream for more information and create your own `myinttypes.h` with the information that you need.

> standards-compliant printf that can handle fixed-width types.

That's simple - cast the types to standard types before printing. `64_t` to `long long`, `32_t` to `long`, `16_t` to an `int` and `8_t` to `char` and print them using standard `%lld`...`%hhd` format specifiers.

> you must provide inttypes.h

That there is no guarantee that `inttypes.h` is provided, that is not a  guarantee that it is not provided - it might be. The question sounds more like a theoretical question - I do not think any common compiler in the wild comes without `inttypes.h`.

Comment: I don't have a broad enough view to evaluate your expectation that compilers for freestanding environments will provide `inttypes.h` despite not being required to do so, but I do note that the standard explicitly describes it as an extending `stdint.h` with features for hosted environments.

Comment: "That's simple - cast the types to standard types before printing. 64_t to long long, 32_t to long, 16_t to an int and 8_t to char and print them using standard %lld...%hhd format specifiers."

I'm unclear on whether you mean the caller or the implementer of printf should be doing this.  If the caller, isn't that basically palming the exact same task onto them with the exact same problems?  If the implementer, don't you still need to manually inspect stdint.h (or the compiler docs) to do that, making the implementation non-portable?

Comment: I meant `int32_t var; printf("%ld", (long)var);`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  A bit icky, but I think the thrust of your answer is use the compiler provided inttypes.h anyway, even for freestanding because otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: `8_t` to `char` – if *me* chooses `8_t` as data type I'm usually interested in having a small numeric data type, so I'd be interested in numeric output as well, thus I'd cast to `int` instead... When interested in characters (text) I'd use plain `char` right from the start (luckily a different type than signed and unsigned char...).

Comment: `int` – or `unsigned` – met a system once with `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`, signed `int` for `unsigned char` would have badly failed there for large values...

Answer (score 0):

> This means that when compiling for an unhosted environment (say bare-metal), you must provide inttypes.h yourself if you want to provide a standards-compliant printf that can handle fixed-width types.

No, it does not mean that at all.

Perhaps you have the wrong idea about the fixed-width types.  Those that are provided by a given implementation (which need not be any of them at all) are usually standard integer types of that implementation.  The type names declared in `stdint.h` are then *aliases* for appropriate standard types, not designations of extended integer types.

Thus, the macros in question define string literals that ordinarily contain a *standard* conversion specifier, possibly with a length modifier, such as `"d"`, `"hu"`, or `"lx"`.  If you want to provide a `printf` compatible with the one a hosted environment would provide, then you need to support all the standard conversion specifiers and all the length modifiers relevant to each one, entirely without regard whether those macros are defined or what their replacement text may be.

I guess it's possible that you would run into an implementation (even a hosted one) that provides fixed-width types that it in fact does not use among its standard integer types.  To support such types with your `printf`, you would probably need to extend it to provide new conversion specifiers, but in that case, that's part of your `printf` implementation, so you know how to define the corresponding macros.

Any way around, the macros are relevant only to `printf` callers, not implementers, except inasmuch as you might find it convenient to write  definitions of those macros in conjunction with implementing `printf`.

> I cannot figure out how to correctly determine at compile-time what each macro should be without manually inspecting the implementation's stdint.h [...] Is there a standard way to do this?

No.  That's why the macros are provided *by the implementation* in the first place.  However, callers don't necessarily need to know.  They can instead convert their fixed-width types to guaranteed-wide-enough standard types of their implementation, and use the correct standard conversion specifier for that type.  That's cheap and pretty easy with `printf`.  If you also mean to provide a `scanf`, however, then the corresponding adapter code is a little less convenient.

Comment: "except inasmuch as you might find it convenient to write definitions of those macros in conjunction with implementing printf."

Working on the assumption that callers are expecting a standards-compliant function (and assuming that fixed-width types are supported), I think it's necessary for a provided printf to also provide the relevant macros.  Otherwise, you are just handing the problem over to the caller, no?

Comment: @Fraggle, "necessary" is far too strong a characterization, because callers indeed do have viable workarounds that (at least on the `printf` side) are not very painful.  But let's indeed do talk about expectations for a moment: anyone writing for a freestanding implementation and expecting a standards-compliant `printf` has an unreasonable expectation in the first place.  In the same way, but altogether separately, anyone writing for a freestanding implementation and expecting to have the macros available also has an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: I can see how you assumed I was stating that callers are expect a standard printf from pure freestanding, but that was not my hypothetical.  My question is about how the callee, starting from a freestanding implementation, can *offer* a standards-compliant printf with PRI macros to the caller.  As far as I can make out the answer is "Standard C provides no mechanism to facilitate this specific use case".  Fair enough.

Comment: @Fraggle, I was responding to "Working on the assumption that callers are expecting a standards-compliant function".  The point is that it is not reasonable for callers to have such an expectation, so the assumption is a bit far-fetched.  But if you are determined to provide a `printf` implementation and format macros that conform (but for location of declarations) with the standard library's specs, yes, I already answered that there is no standard mechanism that would provide for defining the macros generically.  Conditional compilation or an external code generator are the best choices.