# Is it possible to access struct members directly as an array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

I would like to be able (if possible) to, through a single variable, access both an array and struct members. The closest I got was the following:

```c
typedef union {
    struct {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };
    float getItem[3];
} Vector3D;
```

However, if things are done this way, everytime I want to access a `Vector3D` variable as an array, I need to do it like this:

```c
Vector3D vec;
vec.getItem[0] = 3.5f; //same as vec.x = 3.5f;
vec.getItem[1] = 8.4f; //same as vec.y = 8.4f;
vec.getItem[2] = vec.getItem[0] + vec.getItem[1]; //same as vec.z = vec.x + vec.y
```

I would like to know if there is any way, with any combination of typedefs, structs, unions and pointers (or with any other tool that C provides), to use the variable as both a struct and a pointer to that struct, to be accessed as an array directly, like this:

```c
Vector3D vec;
vec[0] = 3.5f;
vec.y = 8.4f;
vec[2] = vec.x + vec[1];
```

I've come across a few solutions to similar problems, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524552/access-struct-members-as-if-they-are-a-single-array), but in that question, he suggests to create another variable which is a pointer to the array, whereas I would like to access both the array and the struct with the same variable, with only one declaration (as in my example). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: No there isn’t. To elaborate: a variable has a single type, but you want it to have whatever of the type is determined by the method you use to access it. Nada.

Comment: You would do pointer arithmetic, but it will be more verbose and error prone than the solution that you already have

Comment: No. The way you're currently doing it makes a combination of 3 `float` variables into a pointer to a float (suggested by the array).

Comment: @JL2210 I see no pointers. Just an array. Very different concepts.

Comment: There is a way, if you use slightly different names.  Don't use it, it hides information, and has no benefit, but as you asked...
 `#define veca vec.getItem`  Really, don't do this.

Comment: You still have the problem of padding. If the struct has any padding in between, you are screwed.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito then, if I'm going to use it as it is (with the `getItem` member), would you reccomend to explicitly pack it?

Comment: Pack it? I don't understand it.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito packing the struct prevents the compiler to do any padding on it, as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing). However, as far as I know, this is not necessary in my case, since the struct only holds variables of the same type.

Comment: @Diego Yes, do it explicitly.  The compiler will not add padding normally, but it could.  However, if you don't have a good reason to use this union, I would choose either the array or the struct.