# Invert all bits in a structure in C

Tags: c

What would be an efficient way to invert all the bits of a structure having various members of different sizes?

Sample struct:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t mem1;
    uint8_t mem2;
    uint32_t mem3;
    uint8_t mem4[4];
} sample_struct;
```

Comment: Cast to int[] where the array size is determined by a sizeof(sample_struct)/sizeof(int), then loop over it and use ~ operator?  You'll have to be more specific about 'efficient', perhaps.

Comment: Can you provide an example: what values before and after the inversion?

Comment: Meaning is clear - all of the bits in the memory that correspond to struct fields should be flipped.

Comment: @BadZen Do you mean, flipped by the order (like little endian) or xor-ed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means xor, like x^1.

Comment: @Badzen your suggestion would invoke undefined behavior, it breaks the aliasing rules of C (section 6.5 paragraph 7) and strictly speaking the cast itself would produce an unspecified result.

Comment: Ah, right ok, so char* it is then. (in gcc and some other compilers there are 'pack' directives to get around that - but non-portable of course).    Will compilers do something reasonable efficient with char*, tho?

Comment: @BadZen yes, see my comment on nneonneo's answer (in particular the links to a test case and compiler output).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple and generic way would be to use a function like this:

```
void *memxor(void *p, int val, size_t size) {
    unsigned char *pb = p;
    while (size-- > 0) *pb++ ^= (unsigned char)val;
    return p;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
sample_struct s;
...
memxor(&s, ~0, sizeof s);
```

If for some reason, you want to optimize more, try this:

```
void meminvert(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    if (((uinptr_t)ptr | size) & (sizeof(unsigned int) - 1)) {
        unsigned char *p = ptr, *pe = pb + size;
        while (p < pe) *p++ ^= ~0U;
    } else {
        unsigned int *p = ptr, *pe = p + size / sizeof *p;
        while (p < pe) *p++ ^= ~0U;
   }
}
```

You can try and benchmark if the *optimized* version actually makes a difference. It would take both a huge structure and an unreasonable number of calls.  Optimisation like this is rarely needed and often erroneous.

Comment: Why take an `int` parameter (val) if you only use it as an `unsigned char`?

Comment: @davmac: For consistency with `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);`

Comment: +1, this is a reasonable generic implementation. (I wish that `memfrob` took an actual argument now, instead of just 0x42...)

Comment: @chqrlie fair enough (although, given the chance to correct a bad choice of parameter type, I'd personally have taken it).

Comment: if the structure is really not bigger,this is a very good solution. if the memory buffer is quite large, you may 'chunk' it to the largest machine word available, flip those, and then flip the remaining bytes.

Comment: Although not as colorful as my "graphical" method, this I suspect is more of what OP is looking for.  +1.  :)

Comment: @davmac: making the `val` argument an `unsigned char` may trigger silly warnings from some compilers that will complain about `~0` not fitting in the argument type.  Passing `(unsigned char)~0` would be painful, passing `255` would be non portable, passing `UCHAR_MAX` would be less obvious.

Comment: your "optimized" version is not legal C (it invokes undefined behavior). Please see my comments on nneonneo's answer.

Comment: Why not use `-1` in place of `~0`?

Comment: @David C. Rankin:  I was expecting this question!  Because `-1` is not necessarily the same as `~0`.  C can support architectures where these are different, such as those where integers are represented as sign/magnitude or one's complement.  It would be difficult to find one of these today outside computer museums and purpose made emulators, but for correctness I use `~0`.  Actually, it might be better to use `~0U`...

Comment: That's a fair answer, and the fine slice between `~0` and `~0u` would take a fairly sharp knife given how it is used in context. Thirty-two `1`'s or thirty-two `0`'s are pretty much just that. Just as ones-compliment is allowed on unsigned types... I did enjoy your answer. I have many bit twiddling favorites, many applicable here, but I had not thought about applying them to a generic block of memory before (i.e. something not within `uintX_t` range. This was a good exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, portable, but not necessarily optimal way:

```
char *ptr = (char *)&the_struct;
size_t sz = sizeof(struct sample_struct);
size_t i;
for(i=0; i<sz; i++) {
    ptr[i] = ~ptr[i];
}
```

This is legal because you can cast a pointer to any writable object to `char *` freely.

For more efficiency, you should use a larger pointer, like `unsigned long *`, but then you have to worry about alignment issues (of the start and end). (And, note that it will no longer be strictly legal C, but it will be faster). Example:

```
unsigned long *ptr = (unsigned long *)&the_struct;
size_t sz = sizeof(struct sample_struct) / sizeof(unsigned long);
while(sz-->0) {
    *ptr = ~*ptr;
    ptr++;
}
```

Comment: Technically, you should use `unsigned char` for real portability.

Comment: "And, note that it will no longer be strictly legal C, but it will be faster" - and it might not actually work on real-world compilers which perform optimisations and re-orderings based on type-based alias analysis. Let the compiler worry about optimizing the portable version instead.

Comment: @davmac: There's a reason that I put a big caveat on it. Violating the C spec is something I don't often recommend, but in careful situations (e.g. known compiler or specific embedded platform) such techniques have their uses.

Comment: @nneonneo I do not see your "big caveat". Only "it will no longer be strictly legal C" and warnings about alignment issues. Alignment issues are not the only problem with your proposed code, and if you suggest compiler-specific optimisation then I think you should name at least one compiler on which it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: Also, your "portable" version is missing the `ptr++;` line (and needs it).

Comment: Finally, FWIW, GCC 4.8.4 produces identical code for both versions at -O3 optimisation (for a struct with 4 int members). Test case: http://pastebin.com/AMzqvqru (compiled with -O3 -std=c99) output: http://pastebin.com/HxfL77kJ

Comment: @davmac: If the code above is isolated in a separate function taking a `void*` argument as I did, you should not have to worry about type-aliasing.

Comment: @chqrlie that's not true. The language doesn't have any exceptions to the aliasing rules (6.5 paragraph 7) based on the pointer for access having been converted to a `void *`. The only exception is for access via a `char *`. Anyway, as I've posted elsewhere, a modern optimising compiler does automatically the optimisation you are trying to do manually.

Comment: @davmac: Heh, this is what I get for mixing pointer incrementation with array indexing...

Answer (score 2):

To invert all bits, the logical not `~` operator is your friend. With the 96 bits in the struct, it is best to negate (take ones compliment) of each struct element. Here is a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t mem1;
    uint8_t mem2;
    uint32_t mem3;
    uint8_t mem4[4];
} sample_struct;

/* toggle all bits in type sample_struct */
void toggle_sample (sample_struct *a)
{
    register unsigned char i = 0;

    a->mem1 = ~a->mem1;
    a->mem2 = ~a->mem2;
    a->mem3 = ~a->mem3;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        a->mem4[i] = ~a->mem4[i];
}

int main (void) {

    sample_struct a = {0,0,0,{0}};
    unsigned i = 0;

    printf (" \nThe struct values with all bits '0':\n\n");
    printf (" mem1 : %d\n mem2 : %d\n mem3 : %d\n", (int)a.mem1, (int)a.mem2, (int)a.mem3);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("   mem4[%d] : %u\n", i, a.mem4[i]);

    toggle_sample (&a);        /* toggle all bits in a */

    printf (" \nThe struct values with all bits '1':\n\n");
    printf (" mem1 : %hu\n mem2 : %hhu\n mem3 : %u\n", (int)a.mem1, (int)a.mem2, (int)a.mem3);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("   mem4[%d] : %u\n", i, a.mem4[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_invert

The struct values with all bits '0':

 mem1 : 0
 mem2 : 0
 mem3 : 0
   mem4[0] : 0
   mem4[1] : 0
   mem4[2] : 0
   mem4[3] : 0

The struct values with all bits '1':

 mem1 : 65535
 mem2 : 255
 mem3 : 4294967295
   mem4[0] : 255
   mem4[1] : 255
   mem4[2] : 255
   mem4[3] : 255
```

Answer (score 1):

as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784782/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-a-struct-with-elements-of-diferent-types-in-c)

you could do: (pseudo code)

```
#define X_FIELDS \
    X(uint16_t, field1, ) \
    X(uint8_t, field2, ) \
    X(uint32_t, field3, ) \
    X(uint8_t *, field4, [4])
//define the structure, the X macro will be expanded once per field
typedef struct {
#define X(type, name, num) type##num name;
    X_FIELDS
#undef X
} mystruct;    
void flip(mystruct *aStruct)
{
//--- "iterate" over all the fields of the structure
#define X(type, name, num) \
         aStruct->name ~= aStruct->name;
X_FIELDS
#undef X
}
//--- demonstrate
int main(int ac, char**av)
{
     mystruct a = { 0, 1, 2, {1,2,3}};
     flip(&a);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take care about data alignment.

Structures in C unless you do not specify at begining of the program

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

are aligned.

That means that something called "data padding" happens.

And you will notice with amazement that calling sizeof on your structure do not returns 11 but returns 12 :) .

Comment: OK, but this doesn't answer the question. (note that flipping the bits of a structure's padding is an operation that isn't ordinarily visible to a program anyway).

Comment: It actually answered,use a method proposed by the people above and use a 

#pragma pack(push, 1)

//define structure

#pragma pack(pop)

Comment: good point - but it should not matter,since the data type has no influence on the result.if you flip to uint8 instead of one uint16 it does not matter